# gridExtra::read.tiff and missing resolution info

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2, tiff

To assemble multi-panel figures I'm writing a function that uses gtable to nicely and automatedly arrange them. I'm implementing functionality to add `*.tif` graphics as panels and am running into problems determining the resolution after reading the file.

```
# Plot something
require(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))
p <- p + geom_point()

# Save as tif
tmpFile <- tempfile(fileext = ".tiff")
ggsave(
  filename = tmpFile,
  plot = p, 
  width = 65, 
  height = 60, 
  units = "mm", 
  dpi = 300)

# Re-read
require(gridExtra)
require(pixmap)
parsedTif <- read.tiff(tmpFile)
```

There's one warning issued, which is related, but I cannot place:

```
Warning message:
In rep(cellres, length = 2) : 'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL
```

When I do this, `parsedTif@size` gives me the dimensions in pixels, but `parsedTif@cellres` equates to `c(1, 1)`. In this constructed case I know the actual measurements that the image should have and can thus reconstruct the resolution like so,

```
dim <- parsedTif@size
size <- unit(x = dim/11.8, units = "mm")
```

but that's not generally known. How do I get the resolution from a `gridExtra::read.tiff` parsed object or is this just an issue with `ggsave` produced tiffs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more googling it appears that the observed behavior is a bug in the `pixmap` package (see e.g. [here](http://tinyurl.com/mnldnuz) for another instance). Switching to `tiff::readTIFF` fixes the issue - resolution is reported properly. `rtiff::readTiff` recapitulates above behavior from `gridExtra::read.tiff` and is thus also unusable.